# Specify default value to FormControl of react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

In `react-bootstrap@0.24.5` I've used `Input` attribute `defaultValue` to specify start value selected in combobox

```
<Input type='select'
             ref='templateSelect'
             defaultValue={this.state.templateId}
             onChange={this.handleTemplateChange}>
   {options}
</Input>
```

How this should be handled in `react-bootstrap@0.30.7` ( newest one ) where `Input` was deprecated and new component that should be used here `FormControl` doesn't provide such attribute?

Should `value` be used instead?

```
<FormControl type='select'
             ref='templateSelect'
             value={this.state.templateId}
             onChange={this.handleTemplateChange}>
   {options}
</FormControl>
```

Or maybe something like this:

```
value={this.state.templateId || 'default value'}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the `FormControl` value attribute pretty much corresponds to the regular `input` value attribute, so using value to set default, as above, should work fine. I wouldn't recommend `value={this.state.templateId || 'default value'}`, since in case your change handler sets the `this.state.templateId` to something that resolves to `false`, the shown value in the input field would be 'default value'.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I didn't test this, but from the React Bootstrap [source code for FormControl](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/FormControl.js) it seems like using `defaultValue` prop should work:

```
<FormControl type="select"
  ref="templateSelect"
  defaultValue={this.state.templateId}
  onChange={this.handleTemplateChange}>
   {options}
</FormControl>
```

If multi select defaultValue must be array:

```
this.state = {
  templateId:['some value']
}
<FormControl 
  multiple
  type="select"
  ref="templateSelect"
  defaultValue={this.state.templateId}
  onChange={this.handleTemplateChange}>
   {options}
</FormControl>
```

Comment: defaultValue is not working! I am using the same code.

Comment: Note that this might have changed in Bootstrap 5. Use the `value=` prop instead

Answer (score 7):

With `"react-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.14"`, the `value` prop is used:

```
<Form.Control as="select" value={user}>
    { users.map(opt => (<option>{ opt }</option>)) }
</Form.Control>
```

Comment: He actually asked for a default value not actual value.

Comment: @klendi the default value doesn't work, the value prop does: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2091

Answer (score 4):

(Hi googlers!)

If you are attempting to load an array of options into the Form-Control (By a network-call, promise or other async function) make sure you dont render the Select-field until the options-array has been fully loaded. Or else the defaultValue wont work.

(True for react-bootstrap 1.0.0-beta.8. Your mileage may wary.)

Comment: It is true today 02/09/2022 with `"react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",`

Answer (score 2):

This way you can set the default value.

```
                <option  >is any default</option>
                {

                    dataoption.map(item => {

                        return <option key={item.Value} value={item.Value} selected={defaultselect ? defaultselect == item.Value ? true : false : false}  >{item.Text}</option>
                    })
                }

            </FormControl>
```

You may receive an error in the console:

Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  instead of setting `selected` on .

But setting defaultValue or value does not solve your problem